# How to fix contract violation for lists of list in racket?

Tags: racket

I am learning Racket for understanding principles of programming languages. What I am doing is to add only second elements in pairs of a list. In my understanding, I think I am doing correctly. However, the error message shows up. Please provide me any advise to understand what I am doing wrong.

```
(define pairs
 '((1 5)(6 4)(7 8)(15 10)))
```

```
(define (secondSum lst)
  (if (null? lst) 0
      (+ (cdr (car lst)) (secondSum (cdr lst)))
      )
  )
```

```
>(secondSum pairs)
```

```
+: contract violation
  expected: number?
  given: '()
  argument position: 2nd
  other arguments...:
   10
```

What I am looking for is

```
(5 + 4 + 8 + 10)
```

Comment: null? lst -> (+ 5 (+ 4 (+ 8 (+ 10 0)))) and
null? (cdr lst) -> (+ 5 (+ 4 (+ 8 0)))

Answer (score 0):

`(cdr (car lst))` should be `(car (cdr (car lst)))` also `(cadr (car lst))` or in racket preferred `(second (first lst))` that is if `lst` is `'((1 5))` the result should be `5`.

I had to be sure this was right so I ran the program with the fix and verified the result:

```
(define pairs '((1 5)(6 4)(7 8)(15 10)))

(define (secondSum lst)
  (if (null? lst) 0
      (+ (car (cdr (car lst))) (secondSum (cdr lst)))
      )
  )

(secondSum pairs)

(+ 5 4 8 10)
```

The last two expressions both have the value `27`.

Comment: Thank you for you answer. It is still showing the same contract violation. Is there more things to fix? I changed '(if (null? lst) 0' to '(if (null? (cdr lst)) 0' However, it does not add the last one which is 10. Still looking.